# In Yii2 how to use array index as $key when using ArrayHelper::map() method?

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, array-map

```
$lang = [
   'en' => ['id'=>'1', 'name' => 'English', 'short' => '1', 'active' => '1',],
   'tn' => ['id'=>'2', 'name' => 'Tamil', 'short' => '2', 'active' =>'1',],
]; // sample array`
```

In yii2 i can use the array map method as follow.

`ArrayHelper::map($lang,'id','name');`

But how to put the array index ('en' and 'tn') in the place 'id' 

`ex:ArrayHelper::map($lang, array_index,'name');`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a function of ArrayHelper as far as i know, but can't you just make your own? Give something like this a shot:

```
function YourArrayHelper($arr)
{
    $returnArr = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        $returnArr[$key] = $value['name'];
    }
    return $returnArr;
}

$types = [
    'en' => ['id'=>'1', 'name' => 'Sell', 'short' => '1', 'active' => '1',],
    'tn' => ['id'=>'2', 'name' => 'buy','short' => '2', 'active' =>'1',],
]; // sample array

var_dump(ArrayHelper::map($types,'id','name'));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(YourArrayHelper($types));
```

Comment: Thank you.  Will follow your suggestion.